# Fix Pandas dataframe bug?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Need help! I am just trying to add each value in column "number" to +1, from  "3 ,4 ,5 , 6 ...." to "4, 5, 6, 7...." but it seems like when I pass the function to the dataframe key, things didn't work well, I don't know why it didn't work... can anyone fix my code?
[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKl3i.jpg)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwRxK.jpg)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JQKq.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! On this site, we prefer that you post the actual code instead of an image of it. It's easier that way for answerers to reference it.

Comment: You don't need a function for that. You can just do `df['number']=df['number']+1`

Comment: By the way, it is not a bug in Pandas. It s the way you have written your function. It is going over all the number & returning only the last number plus 1. Try changing the last number to a 100 & you will get 101 for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Number'] = df['Number'] + 1
```